# Group Anagrams algorithm performance

Tags: javascript

I created an algorithm to create lists of anagrams

The input is `["eat", "tea", "tan", "ate", "nat", "bat"]`

Then, the output should be:
`[["eat","tea","ate"],["tan","nat"],["bat"]]`

Each array is words that are anagram.

My solution is:

```
function group(input) {
    let result = [];
    if(input.length === 0){
        return result;
    }

    for(let i=0; i<input.length; i++){
        let check = true;
        for(let j=0; j<result.length; j++){
            if(result[j].includes(input[i])){
                check = false;
            }
        }
        if(check){
            result.push(checkAnagrams(input, i)); 
        }
    }

    return result;
}

function checkAnagrams(aStr, i){
    let anagrams = [];
    anagrams.push(aStr[i]);
    for(let j=0; j<aStr.length; j++){
        if(i !== j){
            if(isAnagram(aStr[i], aStr[j])){
                anagrams.push(aStr[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return anagrams;
}

function isAnagram(str1, str2) {
    // split => string into array
    // sort => sort the array
    // join => string to array
    // trim => remove any space
    const string1 = str1.split("").sort().join().trim();
    const string2 = str2.split("").sort().join().trim();
    if(string1 === string2){
        return true;
    } 
    return false; 
}
```

I know it works, but I was wondering if there is a better way to implement it.

Thanks

Comment: "better" and "performance" are totally distinct concepts. Please clarify what you need here. This _may_ be more on topic for Code Review SE, but please see their [on topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) help article before asking to ensure you can rephrase the post to work for that site.

Comment: If the code works and you need it to be optimized, you should ask on Code Review instead.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is better off asked on Code Review.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't know about the code review section.

Comment: I'm asking because if my input is too big, the program crashes.

Comment: I don't know if it's an improvement, but instead of comparing each character, sort the words and compare the sorted words...  "ate" and "tea" sorted are both "aet"...

Comment: I think it's what I am doing in the isAnagram method

Comment: If you use the sorted, you can create an object with the sorted word as the key, and an array of the words as the value, and when done, either use that object, or get an array out of it...

Comment: Could you show me an example?